# Autolayout works when viewController is loaded from XIB but does not work when loaded from Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I Have a project [here](https://github.com/patchthecode/NSPageCollerError/archive/master.zip). Autolayout constraints is working only when loaded from a Xib file.

When you run the project you will see a single screen with a NSPagecontroller on it that has two views (swipe left/right to get the other view).

Both views are exactly the same with the exact same auto layout constraints on it. One is loaded using Xib, while the other is loaded using Story board.

Try resizing the window when the xib loaded one is on screen. You can see every thing resizes correctly. Now swipe the screen left. Try resizing the window now. The view loaded from story board will not autosize.

Is this Apple bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views are not exactly the same. If I delete the view in the storyboard, and copy-paste the view from the xib, then the storyboard version behaves as expected.

The trouble with all of this storyboard/xib constraints goodness is that they are a complete pain to debug if something goes wrong.

Try spot the difference:

(1) ViewController.xib

[image]

(2)Storyboard

[image]

For this reason, I tend to handle all of my constraints in code these days.

Top left button comparison:

(1) ViewController.xib

[image]

(2)Storyboard

[image]

The other buttons constraints differ also.

Comment: thanks a mil man. This was stupid. In order to get the constraints of the view to work on story board I had to do what you did. Delete the view from story board and then copy view from the xib unto the storyboard to set as the ViewController's new view. Only then did the view on storyboad have the constraints. Without doing this, it doesnt seem like Interface builder storyboard allows you to set constraints for the view directly under the Viewcontroller.